# How to calculate the $q$-extent of round sphere?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

By definition the **$q$-extent** of a metric
space $X$ is the maximum average distance between $q$ points; i.e.
$$xt_q(X):=\max_{x_1,\dots,x_q}xt_q(x_1 ,\dots ,x_q)$$
where
$$xt_q(x_1 ,\dots,x_q) = {q\choose 2}^{-1}\sum_{i<j}  \operatorname{dist}(x_i , x_j) .$$

The following image is a screenshot of a lecture. There the lecturer calculated the $q$-extent of round sphere which I think it is wrong. because for $q=4$ it fails. What is the correct solution?

I think it should be $2\pi/4=\pi/2$ but how?

[image]

---

**Update:** After a few search, I found the [following example](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/42af/baeea4965d85b0e20581b70d274dddc1310a.pdf?_ga=2.32072950.938462202.1598631362-988218502.1598631362) which shows that my claim is wrong. But I don't understand the author argument. (Or I misunderstood the concept of $q$-extent!! For example, my thought of $4$-extent of $\Bbb S^1$ is that to reach the maximum amount we should put them pair of antipodal points, but this is wrong.)

> **Q:** What does $q$-extent of $\Bbb S^1$ represent  exactly? I know that for $q=2$ it is "diameter".

[image]

Comment: Now I'm wondering whether I've also been in that professor's lectures, or if it's just that most mathematicians have similar chalkboard handwriting.

Comment: Who was that professor? At least what date?